# How do I parse a partial string within a cell in Google AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a long list of names sorted by date, and on each row there is the potential for column P's cell to contain a text string with a price mixed in, for example "DIFFICULT. $5 CUP. CALLING BACK" OR "$10 CUP. CLIENT CURIOUS."

I would like for my function to go down the list, check if the date is today, and if so, check if column P contains "$5 Cup" or "$10 Cup" or any other similar partial string from the cell.
If BOTH of these checks are correct (date = today + column P contains my input somewhere within it) I'd like to have the name added to a table and emailed to me.

I can pull and parse today's date, and I can generate the table and email when it comes to the date, but I am struggling to figure out how to add something in the spirit of [if today = true, search column P for ___].

I attempted to iterate through the rows with today's date and after some googling tried to use findVal and MATCH functions but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not *super* experienced but it also did not seem like an if statement worked the way I intended due to the need to only parse *part* of the cell: using equality operators doesn't seem to work.

Spreadsheet example is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lSdeIvr_7X4JoynmhGSzYSBOgBfszVyYk91hnw3S8ig/edit?usp=sharing

Below is my script, everything works fine except the commented-out "check if client got a cup" section.

```
function cupEmail() {

    //spreadsheet
    var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2023 SALES");
    var mData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2023 SALES").getDataRange().getValues();
    
    //today's date creation
    var today = new Date();
    var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear();
    date.toLocaleString();
    Logger.log(date);

    //variables used for calculating
    var installToday;
    var gotCup = 0;
    
    //table creation
    var cupTable = '<div><table border="1px solid blk" border-collapse="collapse" CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding="5"><tbody><th font-weight="bold"><td>Client Name</td></th>'

    //for loop Cup Clients
    for (var i = 3; i < mData.length; i++) {
        
        //stop script if booked date is empty
        if (mData[i][0]== ''){
            break;
        }
        
        //pull date
        else{
            var x = Date.parse(mData[i][4]);
            var activeDate = new Date(x);
            var day = activeDate.getDate();
            var month = activeDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = activeDate.getFullYear();
            activeDate.toLocaleString();

            //change string from cell into useable "date" form
            var formatted_Date = (activeDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + activeDate.getDate() + "-" + activeDate.getFullYear();
            Logger.log(formatted_Date);
            
            //determine match
            if (formatted_Date === date){
                installToday = true;

                /*
                //check if client got a cup
                if mData[i][12]findVal.match('$5 Cup') || findVal.match('$10 Cup') {
                    var name = mData[i][1];
                    gotCup += 1;
                    cupTable += '<tr><td>'+gotCup+'</td><td>'+name+'</td></tr>'

                }
                */
                
            }
            else{
                installToday = false;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    //table finisher and emailer
    cupTable += '</tbody></table></div>'
    header1 = '<div><h2>'+gotCup+' clients wanted a cup today:</h2></div>'
    body = '<div>'+header1+cupTable+'</div>'
    Logger.log(body)
    var emailAddress = 'email@email.com';
    var message = body + '<p> This message was sent automatically.</p>'
    var subject = 'Cups Today'
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody:message});
}
```

Comment: you only want to validate a particular row if the date on that row is TODAY, right? Can you give us a small sample of what the sheet might look like? And the code you already have that's working?

Comment: Try a regex some like this `/\$\d+\s+CUP/g`.Iif you want more regex example responses then add REGEX to your tags.

Comment: When I saw your script, it seems that `activeTable` is not declared. By this, I'm worried that an error occurs. But, you say `Below is my script, everything works fine except the commented-out "check if client got a cup" section.`. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? And also, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?